# SSRS: How to return last day of a Custom/Financial Month (Not Calendar) through expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

This is a real hair puller so any help, much appreciated!

I want to be able to determine the:

- First day of the current custom/financial month
- Last day of the current custom/financial month

And use these new columns `Start_Date` and `end_Date` as between Filters in the Matrix.

Note: I understand that if this was calendar Month, then that will be "quite" straightforward.

But in this case its quite different.

Please see image which might help with the context i am trying to work with:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is possible using expressions in SSRS but I don;t have time to investigate. In case it's useful, here's how I would do it in SQL.

Again there is probably a more elegant solution but this was what came to me.

I'll reproduced your data plus a few more dates either end for testing which I guessed based on your sample.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(Custom_Date date, Custom_Day int)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('2017-10-26', 28),
('2017-10-27', 29),
('2017-10-28', 30),
('2017-10-29', 1),
('2017-10-30', 2),
('2017-10-31', 3),
('2017-11-01', 4),
('2017-11-02', 5),
('2017-11-03', 6),
('2017-11-04', 7),
('2017-11-05', 8),
('2017-11-06', 9),
('2017-11-07', 10),
('2017-11-08', 11),
('2017-11-09', 12),
('2017-11-10', 13),
('2017-11-11', 14),
('2017-11-12', 15),
('2017-11-13', 16),
('2017-11-14', 17),
('2017-11-15', 18),
('2017-11-16', 19),
('2017-11-17', 20),
('2017-11-18', 21),
('2017-11-19', 22),
('2017-11-20', 23),
('2017-11-21', 24),
('2017-11-22', 25),
('2017-11-23', 26),
('2017-11-24', 27),
('2017-11-25', 28),
('2017-11-26', 1),
('2017-11-27', 2),
('2017-11-28', 3)
```

Then two queries to pull out the correct dates which you could combine if required.

```
SELECT MAX(Custom_Date) FROM @t WHERE Custom_Date < getdate() AND custom_day = 1

SELECT MAX(Custom_Date) 
    FROM @t 
    WHERE 
        Custom_Date > getdate() 
        AND DATEDIFF(d, getdate(), Custom_Date)<=31 
        AND Custom_Day = (
                            SELECT MAX(custom_day) 
                                FROM @t 
                                WHERE 
                                    Custom_Date > getdate() 
                                    AND datediff(d, getdate(), Custom_Date)<=31
                        )
```

FYI: This would be a lot easier if you had a custom month/period and year in your dates table as then you could just look `custom_day` 1 and `max(custom_day)` where the custom month and year are the same as the current date.

Comment: I agree with Alan that you can never have enough supplementary information in your date dimensions.  Using processing time each time you do a query to determine static information seems like an extra maintenance complexity and source of errors compared to every query using a predetermined column (I'm assuming this is not the only report ever written to need this info for your scenario).